# Data Disappears from Repeater after clicking "add row" button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that pulls data in from a reference table. There is a button attached to the repeater that is supposed to add a row. The button adds the row fine, however, when I enter data into the new text box within the repeater and click the add row button again, the data entered into the previously added row disappears.I need that data to stay in those rows that are added by the button and am at a loss:

Page Load code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["dt2"] = null;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Session["dt2"] == null)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select i.reference_id as [Ref ID], r.ref_code as [Ref Code], r.title as Title, r.year as Year, i.pages as [Pages] from item_reference i left join [references] r on r.reference_id = i.reference_id left join item_header h on h.item_header_id = i.item_header_id where h.item_id ='" + cloneItemID.Text + "'", con);
            dt2 = new DataSet();
            sda2.Fill(dt2);
            Session["dt2"] = dt2;
        }
    }

    RptRefs.DataSource = (DataSet)Session["dt2"];
    RptRefs.DataBind();
}
```

Button Click code:

```
protected void btnRefAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt2Data = (DataSet)Session["dt2"];

    for (var i =0; i < RptRefs.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        dt2Data.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Ref ID"] = (RptRefs.Items[i].FindControl("refID") as TextBox).Text;
        dt2Data.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Pages"] = (RptRefs.Items[i].FindControl("Pages") as TextBox).Text;
    }

    var row = dt2Data.Tables[0].NewRow();
    row["Ref ID"] = "0"; 
    row["Ref Code"] = "";
    row["Title"] = "";
    row["Pages"] = "";
    dt2Data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
    Session["dt2"] = dt2Data;
    RptRefs.DataSource = dt2Data;
    RptRefs.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your insert code works and inserts what you think it does?  A good test would be to move your insert code to the page_load with some test values before it's bound the first time.

Comment: This add row should not be inserting data into the database. I have a save button that handles inserts, if that's what you were asking. The data just needs to stay in the repeater after the added row has been modified and add row is clicked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set `DataSource` of the repeater in `Page_Load` even when `IsPostBack` is true. This way the changed data in the repeater is overwritten when the button is clicked and before `btnRefAddRow_Click` is executed.

Change `Page_Load` to only set `DataSource` of the repeater when `IsPostBack` is false.